# Why SequenceEqual for List<long> catch error?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

i have object called schoolrep and this schoolrep contains many education level ids
my linq query give me error

**Specified filter criteria was invalid**

[image]

i will send list of education level ids and i need to return schoolrep who have all education levels that sent in filter

following is the filter , i am trying make it fixed values to test

```
            List<long> lst = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

following is the Expression

```
            Expression <Func<SchoolRepresentative, bool>> filterExpression = x =>
            x.SchoolRepEducationLevels.Select(x=>x.EducationLevelId).SequenceEqual(lst)
```

Comment: Short answer - it isn't supported.

Comment: how can i handle this issue

Comment: At a conceptual level, realise that writing SQL to do this is hard. Then, once you accept that, realise that that is why it isn't supported. :)

Comment: In practice, that means you will likely need to do this in memory rather than in the DB (i.e. pull it all down, then SequenceEqual locally).

Comment: _schoolrep who have all education levels that sent in filter_ but `SequnceEquals` does not do that, it does more.

Answer (score 0):

It means that EF does not support the `SequenceEquals` method when translating your query to SQL.

I don't know that there's an equivalent, compact SQL query (find all objects where its only child objects have IDs 1, 2, and 3).

One option would be to load all objects that have a child of 1, 2, or 3 using `x => lst.Contains(x.EducationLevelId)` as the filter and then checking for the presence of *all* levels in-memory using whatever method you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), you can create an extension method that will translate to SQL for a test expression.

```
public static class IQueryableExt { // using LINQKit
    // searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where all must match for a row
    // testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
    // r => searchTerms.All(s => testFne(r,s))
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AllAre<T, TSearch>(this IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var s in searchTerms)
            pred = pred.And(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)pred.Expand();
    }

    // searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where one must match for a row
    // testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
    // r => searchTerms.All(s => testFne(r,s))
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AnyIs<T, TSearch>(this IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var s in searchTerms)
            pred = pred.Or(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)pred.Expand();
    }
}
```

Assuming you don't need `SequenceEquals` but just that all of `lst` is included, you can now create a filter expression using `AllAre`:

```
var filterExpression = lst.AllAre((SchoolRepresentative sr, long l) => sr.SchoolRepEducationLevels.Select(srel => srel.EducationLevelId).Contains(l));
```